# Is a reference to the seasons required when writing a yadu?

Tags: poetry

I’m [learning](https://poetscollective.org/poetryforms/yadu/) about different rhyming schemes and forms of poetry from around the world, and one that intrigues me a lot right now is the yadu:

> The yadu is a Burmese climbing-rhyme verse. Each of the stanzas —up to three in all— has 5 lines. The first four lines have 4 syllables each, and the last one can have 5, 7, 9, or 11 syllables. The last two lines rhyme in the usual way. The climbing rhymes occur in syllables four, three, and two of both the first three lines and the last three lines of a stanza.

The source I’m learning from immediately points out that a reference to a season should be added:

> There should be a reference to the seasons since the word yadu means “the seasons.

However, I’m wondering if this is a hard requirement or just a recommendation since I’d like to write a riddle with the scheme, following it as strictly as possible to challenge myself.

---

Is a reference to the seasons required when writing a yadu poem?

Comment: Great question - I'm not familiar with the form but perhaps there is a link with the use of 'kigo' or season words and 'kidai' or seasonal feel in Haiku. Ichiki's book 'Suggestive Brevity' (sadly out of print) is good on this, as are William Higginson's works, 'The Haiku Handbook' and 'The Haiku Seasons: Poetry of the Natural World'.
See: https://poetrysociety.org.nz/affiliates/haiku-nz/haiku-poems-articles/archived-articles/seasonality-english-language-haiku-in-search-of-its-vertcial/
and http://www.2hweb.net/haikai/renku/500ESWd.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an authoritative source on Yadu poems, but I at least did some research to try and help.

[This is the best source I could locate, since it provided the most detail](https://www.writersdigest.com/write-better-poetry/ya-du-poetic-forms).

To quote,

> The ya-du is a Burmese poetic form. Here are the guidelines:
>
> - Quintains (or five-line stanzas).
> - Four syllables in the first four lines.
> - The final line has either five, seven, nine, or 11 syllables.
> - The fourth syllable of the first line rhymes with the third syllable of the second line and the second syllable of the third line.
> - The fourth syllable of the third line rhymes with the third syllable of the fourth line and the second syllable of the fifth line.
> - The fourth syllable of the fourth line rhymes with the final syllable of the final line.
> - Subject usually deals with seasons.
> - Most ya-du are written in three or fewer stanzas.

The phrasing of: (Emphasis mine)

> Subject **usually** deals with seasons.

Seems to imply that it is not an absolutely strict requirement, but is strongly suggested for the format.

My suggestion is that if you're doing this as a challenge to yourself, I would try your best to fit a reference to seasons into your Yadu. For extra credit, maybe. If you just can't manage it, or don't feel like it, then it sounds like you don't need to bother.

Have fun!